# import Pandas_Profiling command results in ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0rc0'

Tags: python, valueerror, pandas-profiling

I successfully installed Pandas profiling module using:

```
pip install pandas-profiling
```

from the command prompt (as admin)
I tried importing pandas profiling two ways with the same result:

method 1) `import pandas_profiling`;
method 2) `from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport`

Both resulted in the same error code below with the last line reporting:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0rc0'

Search of this site and others on this particular error turned up nothing that had to do with importing a module.  Not sure what's happening here.  Python version is 3.7.3.  I would appreciate any help in where I went wrong.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e2a33329b6f0> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from pandas_profiling.controller import pandas_decorator
      7 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      8 from pandas_profiling.version import __version__

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\controller\pandas_decorator.py in <module>
      2 from pandas import DataFrame
      3 
----> 4 from pandas_profiling.profile_report import ProfileReport
      5 
      6 

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\profile_report.py in <module>
      9 import yaml
     10 from tqdm.auto import tqdm
---> 11 from visions import VisionsTypeset
     12 
     13 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, Settings

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 from visions import types, typesets, utils
----> 4 from visions.backends import *
      5 from visions.declarative import create_type
      6 from visions.functional import (

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\__init__.py in <module>
      7     import pandas as pd
      8 
----> 9     import visions.backends.pandas
     10     from visions.backends.pandas.test_utils import pandas_version
     11 

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 import visions.backends.pandas.types

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\pandas\types\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 import visions.backends.pandas.types.boolean
      2 import visions.backends.pandas.types.categorical
      3 import visions.backends.pandas.types.complex
      4 import visions.backends.pandas.types.count
      5 import visions.backends.pandas.types.date

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\pandas\types\boolean.py in <module>
      9     series_not_sparse,
     10 )
---> 11 from visions.backends.pandas.test_utils import (
     12     coercion_map,
     13     coercion_map_test,

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\pandas\test_utils.py in <module>
      9 from visions.backends.pandas.series_utils import series_handle_nulls
     10 
---> 11 pandas_version = tuple([int(i) for i in pd.__version__.split(".")])
     12 pandas_na_value = pd.NA if hasattr(pd, "NA") else None
     13 

d:\python37\lib\site-packages\visions\backends\pandas\test_utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 from visions.backends.pandas.series_utils import series_handle_nulls
     10 
---> 11 pandas_version = tuple([int(i) for i in pd.__version__.split(".")])
     12 pandas_na_value = pd.NA if hasattr(pd, "NA") else None
     13 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0rc0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to reinstall force pandas, maybe there is a issue between pandas_profiling version and pandas version.

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas
```

Comment: can you try my answer and make a feedback ? thanks